# mv or (git mv) multiple files, preserve extension

Tags: git, mv, git-mv

I have about 10 directories, each with contents that match this pattern:

```
x.js
x.d.ts
x.ts
```

and I want to rename these files to:

```
index.js
index.d.ts
index.ts
```

is there a mv or git mv command that I can use to rename the files?

something like:

```
git mv --match x.* index.*
```

I am not really sure.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/360082/is-there-a-way-to-use-in-the-destination-of-cp-mv-etc/

Comment: if you think that works pls add an answer

Comment: This question belongs on superuser, not stackoverflow

Comment: mmm, maybe on unix/linux stackexchange, too many windows users on superuser :)

Comment: You can use `git` and `mv` in windows

Comment: of course, but I am on macos at the moment

Answer (score 1):

As git does not perform any special rename registration, you can use system utility like [rename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rename), then stage the changes. For example with commands:

```
git add -u
git add <new pattern>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a directory, you can use the following command:

```
rename x index x.*
```

x.* is the pattern. For all matched file, x will be replaced to index but just for the first occurrence.

Thanks!